# How to set the width responsively in owl.carousel.js?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    items : 3,
    lazyLoad : true,
    autoPlay : true,
    navigation : true,
    navigationText :  false,
    pagination : false,
  });
});
```

Here its my script. I want to display three or more items in mobileview also.I refer the some answers and place it in the script but it will not accept it, the width will take from the js file..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

**The setting of the responsive structure to add your CSS file**

```
responsive : {
    // breakpoint from 0 up
    0 : {
        option1 : value,
        option2 : value,
        ...
    },
    // breakpoint from 480 up
    480 : {
        option1 : value,
        option2 : value,
        ...
    },
    // breakpoint from 768 up
    768 : {
        option1 : value,
        option2 : value,
        ...
    }
}
```

**Add the owl-carousel script add your js file**

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
            nav:true
        },
        600:{
            items:3,
            nav:false
        },
        1000:{
            items:5,
            nav:true,
            loop:false
        }
    }
})
```

Here the documentation link: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/responsive.html